# Accessing variables from another classes with setter and getter JAVA

Tags: java, methods, get, set, getter-setter

This is a very simple example of my project which is a lot more bigger in scale.

Tasks:

- The password will be set at the setpassword method.
- The getpassword method will return the password.
- The password is called at sendmail class  in order to be send via email to the user to log in with the new credentials.

But When I run the whole code everything works except that the sendmail class won't access the password from the getpassword method in users class.

I put a simple version of my code:

users class >>>>>

```
public class  users {


private String password;


public users (){}

// GETTING PASSWORD
public String getpassword(){

    return password;
}


// SETTING PASSWORD
 public void setapassword(String password){
     this.password=password;
 }




}
```

Signup class>>>>>>

```
public class signup {

public void signsup(){

    users  user1 =new users();
    user1.setapassword("player"); 

    sendmail mail1 =new sendmail();
    mail1.Sendsmail();

}
}
```

sendmail class>>>>

```
public class sendmail   {

public void  Sendsmail(){

    users user1 =new users(); // object

    user1.getpassword(); //getting password 

 System.out.println(user1.getpassword()); // If print here I get null
 }
 }
```

Main signup Class>>>>

```
public class SignupMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     signup signup1= new signup();
     signup1.signsup();
   }

 }
```

Comment: You can pass user1.getpassword() in constructor of sendmail class.

Comment: Please make sure you will follow the [java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) so that others can read and understand your code more easily. Thanks.

Comment: where can I read more about the above problem  I have ? such that I understand the concept better .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the standard coding conventions. I changed your code with standard coding conventions. just copy paste it , it will work

Users class

```
public class  Users {
private String password;
public users (){}
// GETTING PASSWORD
public String getpassword(){

    return password;
}
// SETTING PASSWORD
 public void setapassword(String password){
     this.password=password;
 }
}
```

Signup class

```
public class Signup {

public void settingPassowrd(){

    Users  user1 =new Users();
    user1.setapassword("player"); 

    SendMail mail1 =new SendMail(user1);
    mail1.Sendsmail();

}
}
```

SendMail class

```
public class SendMail   {
    private Users user1;
    SendMail(Users user1){
        this.user1 = user1
    }
    public void  sendMail(){
    user1.getpassword(); //getting password 
    System.out.println(user1.getpassword()); // If print here I get null
}
}
```

Main class to test the code

```
 public class SignupMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 Signup signup1= new Signup();
 signup1.settingPassowrd();
}

}
```

Comment: Hats off Buddy !!  It was a whole day that  I was trying to do it !! 
Finally I had the email sent with the credentials of the user!
thanks a lot!

Comment: Well Come ..You can refer my blog posts of Java/J2EE design patterns - http://ramesh-java-design-patterns.blogspot.in/p/start-here.html

Answer (score 2):

The `user1` object from your signup class and your sendmail class are different. Surely their variable is named the same way but they **refer** to different Objects. To access the password from the user you have to pass the user to the sendmail class e.g.:

**Signup.java**

```
public class signup
{

  public void settingPassowrd()
  {
    users user1 = new users();
    user1.setapassword( "player" );

    sendmail mail1 = new sendmail();
    mail1.Sendsmail(user1);

  }
}
```

with:

```
public class sendmail
{

  public void Sendsmail(user usr)
  {

    usr.getpassword(); // getting password

    System.out.println( usr.getpassword() ); // will be the proper value from now on.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in your sendmail class you create a new user `users user1 =new users();` --> so you don't access the user you previously created, but you create a new one which obviously does not have a password.

Instead, pass your user to the sendmail function in the signup class:

```
public void settingPassowrd(){

    users  user1 =new users();
    user1.setapassword("player"); 

    sendmail mail1 =new sendmail();
    mail1.Sendsmail(user1);

}
```

and in class sendsmail:

```
public void  Sendsmail(users user) {
    System.out.println(user.getpassword());
}
```

By the way, I suggest you read some coding guidelines for Java. for example:

- Class names should always start with a capital letter
- Class names are usually singular (`class users` --> `class User`)
- Method names always start with a lowercase letter and use camelCase (`getpassword()` --> `getPassword()`)